# How to ask for X yen worth of something?

Tags: word-choice, counters

I think more or less everything is in the title, say I'd like to buy 1000 yen of carrots, would:

> 人参の1000円分お願いします

Be correct ?

Comment: Note that this follows the same pattern as asking for a quantity of items, e.g. 人参を10本お願いします

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Almost!  It would be:

> 「人参{にんじん}**を**1000円分{えんぶん}お願{ねが}いします。」

Answer (score 5):

unnatural: 人参の1000円分お願いします。
natural: 1000円分の人参（を）お願いします。(You can ommit を, put pause before お願いします）
acceptable: 人参(を)1000円分お願いします。(You can ommit を、put pause before お願いします）